# Copy Date Modified from Finder into Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: finder, copy-paste

I'm on a Mac, looking at a list of files in Finder. I can copy the filename into a Google Spreadsheet by selecting all, copying, and pasting directly into the spreadsheet.

The next column over in Finder is "Date Modified". I would like to get that copied into the spreadsheet as well. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require (to the best of my knowledge) a trip to the Terminal.

Open Terminal.app in /Applications/Utilities and CD to the directory you want to list. Once there type in

```
ls -al
```

And you will get a listing similar to this:

```
MAC:~ steve$ ls -al
total 56
drwxr-xr-x+ 23 steve  staff    782 Apr 27 18:20 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   admin    204 Nov  2  2014 ..
-r--------   1 steve  staff      7 Nov  2  2014 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 steve  staff  14340 May  6 17:51 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwt@  3 steve  staff    102 Sep 12  2013 .TemporaryItems
drwx------   2 steve  staff     68 Jun  1 18:56 .Trash
-rw-r--r--@  1 steve  staff    291 Sep 12  2013 .apdisk
-rw-------   1 steve  staff   1858 May  4 11:14 .bash_history
drwx------  11 steve  staff    374 May 16 18:12 .dropbox
drwxr-xr-x   3 steve  staff    102 Aug 10  2013 .plex
drwxr-xr-x   3 steve  staff    102 Dec 29  2013 .plexht
drwxr-xr-x   3 steve  staff    102 Jun 26  2014 .python-eggs
drwxr-xr-x   3 steve  staff    102 Aug  9  2013 .xbmc
drwxr-xr-x   4 steve  staff    136 Mar 26 13:34 BitTorrent Sync
drwx------+ 10 steve  staff    340 May 26 10:55 Desktop
drwx------+  6 steve  staff    204 Dec 14  2013 Documents
drwx------+  5 steve  staff    170 Apr 30 12:44 Downloads
drwx------@ 20 steve  staff    680 May 28 08:29 Dropbox
drwx------@ 52 steve  staff   1768 Nov  8  2014 Library
drwx---r-x+  9 steve  staff    306 Jun  4 18:30 Movies
drwx------+  5 steve  staff    170 May  5 11:57 Music
drwx------+  3 steve  staff    102 May  5 19:00 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  4 steve  staff    136 Aug  8  2013 Public
iMini2:~ steve$
```

(I've customized my shell a bit so your prompt will look a bit different)

And in there you will have file dates you need.

If you spend a little time with google and the man pages built into the O/S you will find ways to alter the output to suit your particular needs.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been paying attention. I didn't get a response for a while. I didn't do quite the same thing, but I did end up using the terminal...copying the output and pasting it into the spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I still had to go in and edit each value individually because I couldn't get the dates by themselves, but I suppose it "worked" in the end.